# .NET Core 8/ Blazor issue: cannot create an Entity Framework Migration

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

When trying to create a migration for my project with `dotnet ef migrations add Initial` command, I've encoutered the following error `dotnet : You must install or update .NET to run this application.`.

What could be the solution for this? Downgrading Entity Framework to version 5.0.5 and reinstalling the dotnet-ef tool doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could check your .net runtime with

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

make sure you've installed the runtime for .net8

[image]

You could download the runtime here:https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0